# Keep a sound sample playing till button is released android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, soundpool

I am trying to implement a musical keyboard application that will play string sounds. String sounds are needed to be played till the user releases the key.

I am using a small sample of 1 second with the idea of looping the sample using SoundPool on

`MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`,

and stopping it as

`ACTION_UP`

gets called. But looping does not seem to work. I can put a "long enough" sound sample assuming no user would keep the button pressed for that long, but that is not quite the way I want the app work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:
inside onCreate()

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.beep);

b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mp.stop();
                mp=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.beep);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This works, but looping is not smooth. I used a 1 second long sine wave sample. At the point where the sound ends one loop and starts again (i.e. at the start of each repeatation) there is some odd clicking sound introduced

Comment: can you send me that audio... let me check

Comment: You can just create that by clicking Generate -> Tones -> Sine, 440Hz, amplitude: 1, duration: 1sec on Audacity. I don't know how to send you the sound file